# Question about CE 2.1.5 download

Tags: magento2

This may be a stupid question, but why does the latest version of Magento (without sample data, downloaded from http://magento.com) not include any files within the app directory? I successfully installed, but when looking at the code there is only **app/design/frontend** & **app/design/adminhtml** directories but nothing inside. All the other folders in the root directory have the expected files.

Seems strange as everything is working on the admin. This is for 2.1.5

Answer (score 3):

**app/code** is where your custom modules will go, **app/design** is for custom themes. Magento's own modules and themes (and any other extensions installed by composer) are found in the vendor directory.

After installation is complete, the **app** directory will also contain several configuration files.